# Powershell WebRequest : the request was aborted: the connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: powershell

I've found quite a few references to this problem, but just about all of the answers suggested to either enable tls12 or turn off the certificate check.  I have the tls12 enabled and it's not working.  I did try turning off the certificate check to see if it'd work and it didn't.  I feel like that wouldn't be a good idea to go to production anyways.

I'm trying to do a post request in a powershell script.  I've been able to do a GET request, but the post requests keep failing.

Powershell version is 5.1

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$ids = @{}

$ids.Add(10)
$ids.Add(15)
$ids.Add(20)
Write-Output $ids

$loadToken = "token"
$loadUrl = "https://example.com/token/load/" + $loadToken
$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $loadUrl

Write-Output $token.token

$printToken = "print token"
$printUrl = "https://example.com/post-route/" + $printToken

$params = @{
_token = $token.token
ids = $a
} | ConvertTo-Json

Write-Output $params

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $printUrl -Method Post -Body $params -ContentType "application/json"
Write-Output $response
```

This is the output that I'm getting:

```
0
1
2
10
15
20
{loaded token}
{
    "ids":  [
                    10,
                    15,
                    20
                ],
    "_token":  "token value"
}

Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
At C:\path\to\script\test.ps1:28 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $printUrl -Method Post -Body $para ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo        : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + Fully QualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestWebRequestCommand
```

Edit: updated urls to be clear that web requests are for the same domain.

Comment: Are ```https://url/token/load/``` and ```https://post-url/``` on the same domain (e.g. ```https://example.org/token/load``` and ```https://example.org/```) or a they different domains?

Comment: They are both the same domain.